# Why is jQuery deleting last character of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following jQuery working in a Confluence page to get user input and some auto-suggested links, and POST them both to forms in an external page. However the user input is coming out with the last character truncated. No matter what the length, it lops off the last letter.

For example if the user types `foobar` the POST sends `fooba`. If the user types `foobar foobar foobar`, that turns into `foobar foobar fooba` and so on.

The code that matters is the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('form.aui').on('keypress', showHead);
    function showHead() {
     $('.suggestHead').delay(500).fadeIn(300);
     $('.alertReq, .asterisk').css('visibility', 'hidden');
 var dropdownText = ($( "div.searchContainer2  a.content-type-page span" ).text());
     $('#capture').val( dropdownText );
     var inputvalue = $("#input2").val( );
     $('#describe' ).val( inputvalue );
    };    
  });
```

It's only the `#describe` value that's the problem.

There's a built-in Confluence field that I gave an ID of "#input2", and when a user types into it, the jQuery above assigns the user input to a variable called `inputvalue`, then assigns that variable to a hidden form field I created with an ID of "#describe". (This is so I can use POST on the form, and for other reasons).

If I set up an alert to see what's in `#describe`, like this:

```
//Alert function to test selectors
  $(document).on('click','.searchHeading2',function(){
     alert ($("#describe").val());
});
```

The alert contains what the user typed into `#input2` but with the last letter deleted. This is also what ends up in the form on the page I'm submitting to. Anyone know why it does this?

EDIT: Sorry I edited to fix the `AJS.$` I had left in two spots. That's the Confluence convention for jQuery, you have to replace `$` with `AJS.$`, and replace `$( document ).ready(function() {` with `AJS.toInit(function() {`. I wanted to make it just regular jQuery here so it wouldn't be confusing. Should be right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by A. Wolff in comment:

Use keyup event instead